# Tableau: Getting Aggregate Count Based on Boolean Attributes

Tags: tableau-api

I am really new in Tableau and I would be needing help in some calculation.
My simplified data consists of three columns:

```
customer no, transaction date, lost_flag
```

here lost_flag is a boolean which marks as true if a customer made a transaction in the last 365 days.

```
(max([transaction date)< dateadd('year',-1,max([Report Date])))
```

I need to find the:
1. number of customers that are lost
2. number of customers that are not lost
3. attrition rate

For number one, I initially did

```
countd(if ([Lost_flag]) then [Customer No] else "" END)
```

But obviously it did not work.

Note: Customer_No is not unique here since this is a transactional sales data source

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your lost flag is being calculated at the customer level rather than the transaction level. In order to do this use the following formula, note that it is similar to yours however I have made it be fixed at customer id and also replaced  report date with todays date:

```
Lost Flag = { FIXED [Customer ID]: (max([Transacton Date])<dateadd('year',-1,max(TODAY())))}
```

This will add a TRUE or FALSE flag against every transaction for a customer.It is important that this is fixed at the customer id level rather than the transaction otherwise all old transactions for a customer will be flagged as lost even if they have a recent transaction.

So in order to see how many customers are lost do the following: 
1) drag lost_flag onto the rows shelf
2) drag customer id onto the text mark and then right click- measure - count distinct.

Comment: I tried the LOD but it failed.  "Argument to sum is already an aggregation, and cannot be further aggregated"

Comment: Can you screenshot your LOD calculation definition?

Comment: updated my response based on the information you provided, this should give you the answer now :)

Comment: Works perfectly @smb :) Is there also a way I can integrate the count of distinct lost customersso I can have an attrition %? Like a  count of lost customers / countd(Customer ID)? I'm not sure how to do the numerator in this case

Comment: see if this works { FIXED :
sum(if [Lost Flag] = TRUE
then 1
else 0
end)
/ 
COUNTD([Customer Id])}. Also if my answer was helpful could you give it a vote :)